# What happened to MySQL 6 & 7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

With the recent release of MySQL 8, I can't seem to find any information about why version numbers 6 and 7 were skipped.  Anyone know?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [Dave Stockes](https://twitter.com/stoker), a MySQL Community Manager for Oracle:
<sub>(from his blog post: [MySQL 8 is coming](https://opensource.com/article/17/2/mysql-8-coming))</sub>

> Years ago, before the Sun Microsystems purchase of MySQL AB, there was a version of MySQL with the number 6. Sadly, it was a bit ambitious and the change of ownership left it to wither. The MySQL Cluster product has been using the 7 series for years. With the new changes for MySQL 8, developers feel they have modified it enough to bump the big number.

Wikipedia article about MySQL also has these events:

> - Sun Microsystems acquired MySQL AB in 2008.
> - Version 5.1: production release 27 November 2008 (event scheduler, partitioning, plugin API, row-based replication, server log tables)
>     MySQL 5.1 and 6.0-alpha showed poor performance when used for data warehousing – partly due to its inability to utilize multiple CPU cores for processing a single query.
> - MySQL Server 6.0.11-alpha was announced on 22 May 2009 as the last release of the 6.0 line. Future MySQL Server development uses a New Release Model. Features developed for 6.0 are being incorporated into future releases.
> - Oracle acquired Sun Microsystems on 27 January 2010.
> - Work on version 6 stopped after the Sun Microsystems acquisition. The MySQL Cluster product uses version 7. The decision was made to jump to version 8 as the next major version number.

---

And for anyone who wants to see the code, here is a repository: [MySQL 6.0 binaries and source code](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-6.0/) **(6.0.11-alpha)**.

Comment: I'll add source: https://opensource.com/article/17/2/mysql-8-coming

Comment: No. 6 was meant to have a next-generation storage engine  (Falcon) written by [Jim Starkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Starkey) who jumped ship from MySQL just after they were bought by Sun. Falcon [died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(storage_engine)) and (I never knew this (from above) there was a sort of a 7, and now there's 8.

Comment: Meanwhile, MariaDB delivered 5.2, 5.3, 5.4.  Then they got back together with 5.5.  But at 5.6, MariaDB was diverging enough to avoid the same numbering; so it leaped to 10.0.

Comment: So, why 8.0 instead of 5.8?  After all, Oracle's predecessor is 5.7.  8.0 has a number of major upheavals in the core code, so it deserves being considered a "major" release.

Comment: So MySQL skipped 6 for much the same reason PHP did.